# executing a tmux command normally containing '\;' using subprocess.run

Tags: python, subprocess, tmux

First of all, yes. I did read a few questions concerning this issue, and I do understand that escaping should be unnecessary (I even specified `shell=False`).

my issue is that

```
subprocess.run(['tmux', '-n top', 'top', '; neww'])
```

causes a tmux session to open and immediately close

I am trying to achieve the same result as executing

`tmux new -n top top \; neww`

in the shell.

I have also tried specifying `shell=True` and using `'\\; neww'` as well as `r'\; neww'`

it does not appear that anything is being written to stderr either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each argument needs to be individual:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run(['tmux', 'new', '-d', '-n', 'top', 'top', ';', 'neww'])
CompletedProcess(args=['tmux', 'new', '-d', '-n', 'top', 'top', ';', 'neww'], returncode=0)
>>>
```

Comment: Good answer, but perhaps you could expand a bit on how shell quoting works.

Comment: did you test this? because it does not work. Also, I'm sorry, but `subprocess.run(['tmux', '-n top', 'top'])` works as expected so this is just incorrect.

Comment: Yes I did, and it does work. What do you see when you try it?

Comment: absolutely nothing

Comment: Right, that is correct. And when you attach to tmux, do you see the windows you expect?

Comment: yes this does work thank you, also with the -d removed. But why does `subprocess.run(['tmux', '-n top', 'top'])` work as expected?

Comment: Is it because it's throwing out `-n top` and the window is getting named top anyway because it's running top?

Comment: It doesn't work, are you actually doing `['tmux','new','-n top','top']`? That works because tmux passes the `new-session` arguments it gets from Python as a set of strings through getopt and to getopt '-n top' is parsed as '-n' and ' top' - the same way '-nfoo' would be '-n' and 'foo'. You should be seeing a leading space on your window name.

Comment: yes, there is a 'new' in there. it was actually in each example, I sort of condensed the actual code and left that part out in my question. Thank you for your responses.